# Building contravariant using Stack leads to constraint error about not being able to deduce Contravariant

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

When building my project, I get errors like the following:

```
   /tmp/stack19408/contravariant-1.5/src/Data/Functor/Contravariant/Divisible.hs:233:10: error:
        • Could not deduce (Contravariant (Backwards f))
            arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
          from the context: Divisible f
            bound by the instance declaration
            at src/Data/Functor/Contravariant/Divisible.hs:233:10-47
        • In the instance declaration for ‘Divisible (Backwards f)’
        |
    233 | instance Divisible f => Divisible (Backwards f) where
        |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I can't figure out exactly what is going on here, or whether the mistake is on my end or a problem with the libraries involved. Did I do something wrong?

---

I've tried to create the smallest project possible that leads to this problem. In a blank Stack project, change the resolver to `ghc-8.6.2` and add the dependencies:

```
extra-deps:
- contravariant-1.5
- StateVar-1.1.1.1
- base-4.12.0.0
- array-0.5.2.0
```

Add `contravariant` to `dependencies` in `package.yaml`, and import `Data.Functor.Contravariant.Divisible` in `Lib.hs`. This led to compile errors when running `stack build`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not you - released packages are not yet caught up for base-4.12.

Now that the `Contravariant` class is in `base`, the instance for `Backwards` should move to `transformers`, where the latter is defined.  There's [a patch that adds the instances](https://hub.darcs.net/ross/transformers/patch/b00658faa4578b0eb578cf158c75185c1c0ec697) but I don't think it's been released to Hackage.

In your shoes, I would:

1. checkout the darcs repo locally
2. add the local checkout as an `extra-dep`
3. bug the maintainers to release `transformers`